# IBM Knowledge Studio - Advanced Rules Workspace : cannot export advanced rules model zipfile

Tags: ibm-watson, watson-nlu, watson-knowledge-studio

First of all, I want to greet and thank warmly this great community, you guys have helped me countless times with all kind of issues and problems.

Now, back to the issue part...

I'm trying to save a zip file containing my developed model to deploy it on NLU using IBM Knowledge Studio Advanced Rules Workspace, [full documentaint],[1](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/natural-language-understanding?topic=natural-language-understanding-customizing#advanced-rules)  but when I click on Export, selecting my developed extractor

[image]

it fails to save the zip file, so I cannot proceed anymore

[image]

No error is shown by the application itself, but I've seen that "Export as" and "Export to" options in Export Extractors window are not modifiable (the values that are visible in the screenshot are the only one that is present).

Then, I've seen through the console that when I click OK in the window to Export the zip file, the webpage get an error: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wdvpL.png

It seems that it cannot read some zip checkbox inside the Export Extractors window...

[image]

Please help me because I'm completely stuck :(

Answer (score 1):

WKS team has found an issue on the current Advanced Rule Editor and is working on fixing the issue. Sorry for your inconvenience.

Comment: Now it is throwing this error just after opening the workspace.

https://i.imgur.com/1e0h9aG.png

:(

Answer (score 1):

Fix was deployed on IBM Cloud environment and we verified exporting extractor now works.
Please clear your browser cache before trying this.